# Regarding hash, key and value iterator

Tags: java, hashmap

What are hash iterator , key iterator and value iterator in a hashMap and what is their functionality besides the normal iterator , let suppose I have a Hash map..

```
Map map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
      //   System.out.println("Amit".hashCode());
         map.put("Amit","Java");
         map.put("Amit","Javas");
        // map.put("mAit","J2EE");
```

What functionality these new iterator offers me..!

[image: Please see it]

Comment: What is a "hash iterator"? and the "normal iterator"?

Comment: Java has no "normal iterator" nor a "hash iterator". The only ones I can think of are `Map.entrySet().iterator()`, `Map.keySet().iterator()`, and `Map.values().iterator()`.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I believe some old versions of open-jdk7 did have a HashMap.HashIterator http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/HashMap$HashIterator.html

Answer (score 1):

The keySet().iterator() iterates over the keys, the values().iterator() iterates over the values and the entrySet().iterator() interates over the key/value entries.

There isn't any other iterators for a map.

> What functionality these new iterator offers me

They were added in Java 1.2 (1998) so they are not that new. ;)

Answer (score 0):

the results of Map.keySet() and Map.values() are what's called **Collection views** (like if you had a SQL table with two columns and created a separate view for each column). Using .keySet() you get an iterable Collection view of all the keys in the Map. While .values() gives you the ability to iterate over their corresponding values.

They're very handy when you are manipulating a HashMap along with an Array or ArrayList or similar collections. Here i list a simple Java EE example that retrieves a Cookie[] array from a request then store the maps the cookies to a HashMap :

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

for(Cookie cookie : cookies)  
{
  map.put(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
}

//Later if you just wanna check the keys of cookies that are available
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
 String currentElement = it.next();
 System.out.println("key = " + currentElement);

}
```

Anyway that was just a little example of HashMap and iteration in action, important is the possiblity to tweak maps and makes it possible to cycle through them like other collections, means bringing them to a more common and easy to manipulate state programmers use.

Comment: Adding to what Peter stated, here the example shows their use coupled with generics (JDK 1.5+)